# Export a STL class member containing the same class in a DLL interface

Tags: c++, stl

Say I have a class that references itself in a STL container:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Widget {
protected:
    std::vector<Widget *> children;
}
```

If I have say a `vector` of `int` instead, before the class definition I can have the following:

```
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<int>;
```

Which supposedly will work. But how to I do that if the class isn't defined yet? Forward declaring the class:

```
class Widget;
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<Widget *>;
```

Doesn't get rid of the warning I get from MSVC which is;

`warning C4251: 'Widget::children' : class 'std::vector<Widget *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Widget'`

I believe the information in the warning itself is somehow relevant but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Comment: I would try `template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<Widget*, std::allocator<Widget*>>;`

Comment: what about class __declspec(dllexport) Widget as forward declaration istead of the posted one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696593/vc-10-vs-2010-basic-string-exports), the family of these errors are essentially noise;

> C4251 is essentially noise and can be silenced
>   - Stephan T. Lavavej (one of the maintainer's of Micrsoft's C++ library).

So long as the compiler options are consistent through the project, just silencing this warning should be just fine.

**As a more comprehensive alternative** you can look at the [pimpl pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) and remove the `std::vector` from the class definition and thus it would not need to be exported from the dll.

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Widget {
protected:
    struct Pimpl;
    Pimpl* pimpl_;
}
```

```
// in the cpp compiled into the dll
struct Widget::Pimpl {
    // ...
    std::vector<Widget*> children;
    // ...
}
```

[MSDN has a nice article on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438477.aspx) as part of an introduction to newer C++11 features.

In general, it is easier to not use `std` classes in a [dll interface](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach), especially if interoperability is required.

Answer (score 0):

The warning itself was indeed relevant. The header file mentioned in it was installed in a different directory than what I was working on, so my changes were not seen. The correct way to fix the warning is:

```
class Widget;
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<Widget *>;
```

Before the class definition.