# Is exporting stl class members to a dll using an anonymous struct valid?

Tags: c++, stl, dllexport

Here's something I stumbled across when I tried to dllexport a class with a private std::vector member. If I just export the whole class I get the usual warnings (Although you can ignore them with private members). There are of course several ways to deal with this but I found out that it also works if I enclose these members in an anonymous struct like so:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Test{
private:
    struct{
        std::vector<int> data;
    };
};
```

I know that anonymous structs are not standard, but they are supported by the compilers I tested it with (MSVC, GCC). However, is this actually valid or just some nasty hack to get rid of the warnings I should rather avoid?

Edit:
I just noticed that this is similar to the accepted answer for this question here: [Export a STL class member containing the same class in a DLL interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333845/export-a-stl-class-member-containing-the-same-class-in-a-dll-interface). But the difference is that you need an instance of the struct to access the private members. So which method to prefer?

Comment: If I am right, it's okay to export an opaque wrapper struct around an STL class, but only if you only access the STL class from the same side of the boundary that it was created from

Comment: You can export only class methods (including constructor and destructor) so that warning about not exporting members won't appear.